# Error with nested JSON self referencing result set 'aggregate function calls cannot be nested'

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-json

I have following data schema

```
-- table
master 
 - id (int)
 - meta (jsonb)
 - key (string)

-- table
 details 
  - master_id (int)
  - timestamp (timestamp)
  - value     (float)
```

(simplified)

following query terminated with the following error:

```
select json_build_object(
    'name',m.meta->>'name',
    'keys',json_agg(
        json_build_object(
        'key',m.key,
        'checkpoints',json_agg(
            json_build_object(
            'time',d.timestamp,
            'value',d.value)
        )
        )
    )
)
from master m, details d 
GROUP by m.meta->>'name',m.key,d.timestamp,d.value


ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested
LINE 6:   'checkpoints',json_agg(
```

I would like to get the following structure.

```
[
    {"name":"name",
     "keys":[
        {"key":"mykey",
            "checkpoints":[
                {"time":"timestamp","value":"1.2"},...]
        },...]
    }...
]
```

I know the error is quite understandable that I cannot use the `json_agg` nested. But I do not know how to solve it.

This answer recommends using in-inline queries: [PostgreSQL aggregate function calls cannot be nested using jsonb_agg function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572853/postgresql-aggregate-function-calls-cannot-be-nested-using-jsonb-agg-function)

but this does not work for me either or I am missing something.

Help with the query would be appreciated,

EDIT//
Provided a db fiddle with example data and a working results which not includes the checkpoint for each sensor yet.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2XaUFeTcTfFFUrPYsVnYkt/0

Comment: Can you create a db fiddle table with some sample data?

Comment: @eurotrash added the db fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before getting into the queries, note I changed the join conditions. I assume it's accurate to join `details` on id/master_id, because your original query in the dbfiddle didn't seem to return the right results; do you really want `{"name":"x32Z72","keys":[{"key":"sensor1"},{"key":"sensor1"},{"key":"sensor1"},{"key":"sensor1"},{"key":"sensor1"},{"key":"sensor1"}]}` when you have only two records in `details` with id 1?

---

Here are two options:

1: Don't join in the main query, instead do a subquery on `details` to get the checkpoints for each key. The subquery stands on its own so does not have the nested agg call issue.

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'name', meta->>'name',
    'keys', json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'key', key,
            'checkpoints', (
                SELECT json_agg(
                    json_build_object(
                        'time', d.timestamp,
                        'value', d.value
                    )
                )
                FROM details d
                WHERE master_id = m.id
                GROUP BY master_id
            )
        )
    )
)
FROM masters m
GROUP by m.meta->>'name', m.key
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2XaUFeTcTfFFUrPYsVnYkt/1

2: Do the join, but do the aggs on different levels. So first do an agg on the lowest/innermost level (the checkpoints), then you have an outer select to do the higher level agg (keys):

```
SELECT json_build_object(
    'name', name,
    'keys', json_agg(
        json_build_object(
            'key', key,
            'checkpoints', checkpoints
        )
    )
)
FROM (
    SELECT
        m.meta->>'name' AS name,
        m.key,
        json_agg(
            json_build_object(
                'time', d.timestamp,
                'value', d.value
            )
        ) AS checkpoints
    FROM masters m
    INNER JOIN details d ON m.id = d.master_id
    GROUP by m.meta->>'name', m.key, d.master_id
) s
GROUP BY name, key
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2XaUFeTcTfFFUrPYsVnYkt/2

In either case the results are the same:

```
{"name":"x32Z72","keys":[{"key":"sensor1","checkpoints":[{"time":"2018-10-03T00:00:00+00:00","value":1},{"time":"2018-10-03T01:01:12+00:00","value":1.5},{"time":"2018-10-03T00:10:00+00:00","value":2.1}]}]}
{"name":"x32Z72","keys":[{"key":"sensor2","checkpoints":[{"time":"2018-10-03T02:12:01+00:00","value":0.8},{"time":"2018-10-03T06:10:00+00:00","value":1.8}]}]}
{"name":"x32Z72","keys":[{"key":"sensor3","checkpoints":[{"time":"2018-10-03T01:01:12+00:00","value":0.95}]}]}
```